# Can you use SwiftLint on Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, xcode

Is it possible to use SwiftLint with Swift Playground? I'm ramping up on swift and would like to write code in a more standardized way.

Comment: If you're ramping up on Swift, then it might be time to step up to Xcode projects. SwiftLint integration right in the Xcode UI is very good (e.g. the SwiftLint warnings/errors appear right in your code; if looking at list of errors, you can tap on an error and be taken to the offending line; etc.). Plus you're soon going to be running into the performance limitations of Playgrounds, anyway. Playgrounds are fine way to tip your toe into Swift and are fine for simple, one-off, sort of things. But for anything more substantial, you're going to find it increasingly limited.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly it's possible.

You can't do it in some automagic way, like the way your build script phase runs SwiftLint against your code files automatically at build time and produces the output nicely as Xcode errors and warnings.

But SwiftLint is ultimately just a command line tool, and your playground is ultimately just a Swift text file (or a collection of Swift text files), so nothing stops you from running SwiftLint on those files.